# Two topologies on the space of algebraic maps.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

For two complex projective varieties $X$ and $Y$ (not necessarily smooth), the functor that send any scheme $Z$ to $\text{Hom}(X\times_{\text{Spec}(\mathbb{C})}Z, Y)$ is representable by a scheme called the $\mathcal{Hom}(X,Y)$ scheme. Consider the complex points of the scheme i.e. $\mathcal{Hom}(X,Y)(\mathbb{C})$. Does this topological space coincide with the topological space of $\text{Hom}(X,Y)$ endowed with the compact open topology? (considering the algebraic maps as a subspace of continuous maps.)

Comment: Given appropriate topological restrictions on the spaces in question (which should hold for the analytification of the complex points), the compact-open topology satisfies the natural equivalence $Hom(X, Hom(Y, Z)) = Hom(X \times Y, Z)$. This seems to be the same universal property the fiber product you wrote satisfies, so I'd expect this to hold. Perhaps you can approach this problem via that universal property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true and is proved in Section 10.4 of Douady's *Le problème des modules pour les sous-espaces analytiques compacts d’un espace analytique donné*.